# How to disable viber in-app sounds

Tags: notifications, audio, viber-messenger

[image: IMG:]

Hi everyone, appreciate your help on this. How can i apply in android the similar viber setting in iphone to disable the in-app sound?

Basically i still want to hear the viber notification when my phone is locked but i do not want to hear the ding sound when a new message comes in while I'm in the chat thread already.